# Can I add then put this summation into the datatable?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have below code:

```
this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
List<CustomerPayment> paymentList = null;
try {
  org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  Query q = session.createQuery(
    "from CustomerPayment where DATE like '%" + year + "'");
  paymentList = (List<CustomerPayment> ) q.list();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I take this records from `CustomerPayment` table. In this table, there is a `type` field and this type field can have two values `bank` and `cash`

for ex:

```
ID  CODE        DATE        AMOUNT  TYPE
1   CK-00004    11/14/2013  100.5   BANK
3   CK-00004    09/17/2013  250.75  BANK
4   CK-00004    08/20/2013  250.25  CASH
```

What I want is that to sum BANKs amount and CASH amount and put them into the datatable.

How can I do that?

Comment: yeah where TYPE = 'BANK' then sum the banks

Comment: `SELECT type ,SUM(amount) FROM CustomerPayment
GROUP BY type` ?

Comment: @Joop Eggen : You changed the table structure of the OP !!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained, I think I corrected the alignment of the header columns. Precisely as I saw you picking other fields. Now you've corrected the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT type ,SUM(amount) FROM CustomerPayment GROUP BY type
```

will return you :

```
  AMOUNT     TYPE
  BANK       370.75
  CASH       250.25
```

Comment: This way you *fix* the SQL query but lack of the consumption using Hibernate.